# How to do serial communication via rs232 android?

Tags: android

I have an android device 'Micronet A317' which has rs232 44 pins serial port. I have also another device i.e a card reader which has 9 pin D-pad connector. I have connected both device(Android & Card Reader) with each other by using some converter. Now my task is to make serial communication between these two device. 
Please suggest me to do it.

Comment: A 44-pin connector may well be a (low voltage) logic level not RS232 level, so you may have blown out the pins on your board's SOC, but let's hope not.  You need to figure out if your board has a kernel driver active for its serial UART, if there is a corresponding device file, and how to get the code that you want to have use it access rights.  Unless whoever has created your android port has already given you high-level Android-style APIs, make sure you understand how Linux in general handles serial ports before you try to tackle this for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) library to transfer data via serial port on Android. I've tested this library with USB-to-serial adapter + USB-host cable plugged into Nexus 7 USB port.

Your RS232 port should be represented as USB device internally, otherwise this library won't work.

You will also need to know your serial adapter type (FTDI/Prolific/CdcAcm) and add USB device VID/PID to the appropriate driver file to function getSupportedDevices().

You can find out your serial adapter type and VID/PID by running `cat /proc/kmsg` from root shell on your device, or by inspecting directory `/sys/class/tty`